# Apache Camel CXF Transport - Adding interceptors to JaxWs Client

Tags: apache-camel

We are invoking a soap service through RabbitMQ using Camel transport JaxWS client as given below (Ref: http://camel.apache.org/better-jms-transport-for-cxf-webservice-using-apache-camel.html , and used camel-cxf-transport version 2.15.2).

Service invoked successfully, but could not add interceptors to the JaxWS client proxy. Tried the following:

```
<client id="TestService" xmlns="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
        xmlns:testsvc="http://mytest.com/services/test/v2"
        serviceName="testsvc:Test_v2_0_service" endpointName="testsvc:HttpTestPort"
        address="camel://direct:TestService" serviceClass="test.v2.TestSVCV20" >

        <outInterceptors>
            <ref bean="wss4jOutInterceptor" />
        </outInterceptors>

        <features>
            <logging xmlns="http://cxf.apache.org/core"/>
        </features>
</client>


<bean id="wss4jOutInterceptor" class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor">
        <constructor-arg>
            <map>
                <entry key="action" value="testToken" />
                <entry key="user" value="dummy" />
                <entry key="passwordType" value="PasswordTestTxt" />
                <entry key="passwordCallbackClass" value="test.PwdCallbackclass" /> 
            </map>
        </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

When interceptor tag with bean ref is added it is showing the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [ref]
```

Can anyone please help with a sample on how to correctly add the interceptors in camel transport cxf client?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is resolved. Added namespace declaration for spring elements to solve the issue.

Please see the link for more details :

http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Apache-Camel-CXF-Transport-Adding-interceptors-to-JaxWs-Client-td5770596.html

Thanks.